# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'int' and 'float'

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

There's this open source code I was trying out to play checkers, the code works just fine till the taking a piece part, and the following error appears:

```
line 73, in make_move
    taken_piece = int(1 << sum(i for (i, b) in enumerate(bin(move)[::-1]) if b == '1')/2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'int' and 'float'
```

any help regarding how to fix this issue?

Comment: format your code correctly, and then we'll be able to help you

Comment: python 3: use `//2` or you get a float.

Comment: Apparently, this software was written for Python 2 whereas you are trying to run it with Python 3. It's probably only a matter of time until you run into other issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't shift bits by a float/decimal, the error is pretty clear. `sum(...)/2` gives a float in the current operation.

What you can do, however, is perform an integer division using `//`, in Python 3. For Python 2, `/` does an integer division (for int operands) except you've overridden the default behavior.

Comment: In Python 2, it's already an int because both operands are ints. `/` does not do integer division if you do `2.5 / 2` in Python.

Comment: You make it sound like `/` always does an integer division. (let's ignore whether this can be overridden). My point is, that the operation depends on the arguments, since they *both* happen to be ints, it does an integer division, *not* because `/` is used.

Comment: BTW, the answer speaks about `/` when applied to integers. Thank you, updated!